# How to simplify Boolean expression with XOR?

Tags: boolean, expression, simplify

I want to simplify a boolean Expression.
The Expression is something like this

```
X1 xor (X2 || X3 &&  X4 || x5)
```

How do I simplify this expression using rules of Boolean Algebra.

Moreover I want to convert the above boolean expression to a CNF form , so how do I do it.

Comment: @PaulR :- it was suppose to be X3 && X4 || x5)

Answer (score 9):

If you consider that `A XOR B` is equivalent to `(A AND ~B) OR (~A AND B)` then the rest should be easy.

Comment: :-I don't get u what will be the simplification in the above case bcoz in my case A is X1 and B is (X2 || X3 &&  X4 || x5) so how will this be done can u please explain in detail with a example.

Comment: Your `A`is `X1` and your `B` is `(X2 || X3 &&  X4 || x5)`, can you try and work it out from that? Just plug it into the formula @PaulR has provided, simplify and you're good to go

Comment: @Draken: I sincerely hope that the OP is not still struggling with this 4 years after he asked the question! ;-)

Comment: True @PaulR, I was editing an answer from someone else and hadn't looked at the date of the question. Thought it was a new one, ah well :)

Comment: @Draken: yes, I'm not sure why someone decided to add another answer at this late stage - probably just trying to build up some rep.

Answer (score 2):

Write `a xor b` as:

```
a != b
```

or:

```
!(!a || b) && !(a || !b)
```